# Can .Net load a IL file, like java class file, or it has to load a whole assambly?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I'm learning the .Net platform. Can .Net load a single IL file or It has to load a full assembly, that is even there is a single IL file, you have to convert it to an assembly ?

If .Net cannot load a single IL file, I think in there area, the design of java is more simple and good.

why we need to load a assembly, esp. the assembly is a PE file that cannot easily to unpack it like java package.

Answer (score 2):

No such thing *IL file* in the .NET FW, it is actually MSIL and it stands for [Microsoft Intermediate-Language](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMSIL&ei=_tHhU7_5E6e60QWFjoD4Aw&usg=AFQjCNH2xL7RRPXfiKe2J6mazHJYHRk5jg&sig2=9K3lh5aj6kkwNms4d0_v1w&bvm=bv.72197243,d.d2k) which is the language that compiled into a .NET assembly (DLL/EXE) from any high-level .NET language (c#, vb.net etc.).

Comment: What's (if it exists) the compiled `.class` equivalent of a `.cs` file? Can they exist on their own?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In .NET, the equivalent of a `.class` file is either DLL or EXE.

Comment: So you could create a DLL containing a single class and that's how you would distribute it (theoretically)?